# How to calculate number of satellites and horizontal degree of precision in iOS

Tags: ios

How to calculate horizontal degree of precision and number of satellites in iOS.
I have tried with following

```
int horizontalAccuracy = [location horizontalAccuracy];
 horizontalDegreeofPrecision =  horizontalAccuracy/5.0; 
 int verticalAccuracy =   [location verticalAccuracy];
 /// calculating number of satellites
    if (verticalAccuracy > 0) {
        self.numberOfSatellites = [NSNumber numberWithInt:4];///=4
    }
    if (horizontalAccuracy > 300 && verticalAccuracy < 0 ) {
        self.numberOfSatellites = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];///<3
    }
    if (horizontalAccuracy>0 && horizontalAccuracy<60) {
        self.numberOfSatellites = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];///>=5
    }
    if ((horizontalAccuracy>300 && horizontalAccuracy<0)&& verticalAccuracy<0) {
        self.numberOfSatellites = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];///=3
    }
```

Can anyone help me out whether there is any other approach in calculating HDOP and number of satellites in iOS?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: here is some problem in your comparison statements... 'horizontalAccuracy>300 && horizontalAccuracy<0' what does this mean ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using any publicly available iOS API. The only thing I would add is you can assume no of satellites by below code

```
int horizontalAccuracy = [location horizontalAccuracy];
horizontalDegreeofPrecision =  horizontalAccuracy/5.0; 
int verticalAccuracy =   [location verticalAccuracy];
    if (verticalAccuracy > 0) {
        self.numberOfSatellites = [NSNumber numberWithInt:4];///=4
    }
    if (horizontalAccuracy > 300 && verticalAccuracy < 0 ) {
        self.numberOfSatellites = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];///<3
    }
    if (horizontalAccuracy>0 && horizontalAccuracy<60) {
        self.numberOfSatellites = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];///>=5
    }
    if ((horizontalAccuracy>60 && horizontalAccuracy<300)&& verticalAccuracy<0) {
        self.numberOfSatellites = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];///=3
    }
```

Comment: I understood that this is only way to assume no of satellites. But is there any way to calculate horizontal degree of precision in iOS?